# Using sed to erase field in bibtex entry

Tags: regex, sed, bibtex

I'm faced with a text file containing multiple bibtex instances like this one

```
@article{Lindgren1989Resonant,
    abstract = {Using a simple model potential, a truncated image barrier, for the
Al(111) surface, one obtains a resonant bound surface state at an energy
that agrees surprisingly well with recent observations by inverse
photoemission.},
    author = {Lindgren and Walld\'{e}n, L.},
    citeulike-article-id = {9286612},
    citeulike-linkout-0 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.40.11546},
    citeulike-linkout-1 = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib\_query?bibcode=1989PhRvB..4011546L},
    doi = {10.1103/PhysRevB.40.11546},
    journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
    keywords = {image-potential, surface-states},
    month = dec,
    pages = {11546--11548},
    posted-at = {2011-05-12 11:42:49},
    priority = {0},
    title = {Resonant bound states for simple metal surfaces},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.40.11546},
    volume = {40},
    year = {1989}
}
```

I want to erase the abstract field, which can span over one or multiple (like in the above case) lines. I tried using sed in the follwing manner

```
sed "/^\s*${field}.*=/,/},?$/{
    d
}" file
```

where file is a text file containing the above bibtex code. However, the output of this command is just

```
@article{Lindgren1989Resonant,
```

Obviously sed is matching for the final }, but how do I get it to match the closing bracket of the abstract value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed '1{h;d};H;${x;s/\s*abstract\s*=\s*{[^}]*}\+,//g;p};d' file
```

This slurps the whole file into the hold space then deletes the `abstract` fields

Explanation:

On the first line replace the hold space (HS) with the current line, append all subsequent lines to the HS. Upon encountering the last line, swap to the HS and substitute all occurrences of the abstract field then print the file out. N.B. all lines that would normally be printed out are deleted.

Comment: Almost. It keeps }, at the end of the first line here.

Comment: Hm, that version doesn't seem to work at all at my end. Here is what I get with your previous answer http://pastebin.com/J3yfCcmq. Notice how the first line has an extra "}," at the end, which shouldn't be there. Btw thanks for your effort. I'd love to help you figure that out, but I have no idea what your code is actually doing.

Comment: It appears your data can have one or more closing `}`. Solution amended.

Comment: At my end that code you posted doesn't touch the abstract field. It seems like the + sign on the closing bracket (}+) seems to break things. ALso, I think this code will fail if the abstract text itself contains curly brackets, which - unfortunately - can happen.

Comment: Sorry, I've made I right hash and forgot to escape the `+` sign. Try it again!

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thank you! So, why does the + sign need to be escaped, while * doesn't seem to need any escaping?

Answer (score 1):

does this awk line work for you?

```
 awk '/abstract *= *{/{a=1} (a && /} *,$/){a=0;next;}!a' yourInput
```

Answer (score 1):

Addresses in sed match in a weird way:

addr2 can match BEFORE addr1 which is what you are experiencing with your expression!  Use multiple blocks.